# .Net Core PayPal: Client Authentication failed

Tags: paypal-sandbox, asp.net-core-3.1, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm starting to use PayPal for payments with .net Core. I created a sandbox app and checked client id and secret. I get an error at `content`

> "{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}"

Code:

```
private async Task<PayPalAccessToken> GetPayPalAccessTokenAsync(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")
            .GetBytes($"{_configuration["PayPal:clientId"]} : {_configuration["PayPal:secret"]}");

        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/v1/oauth2/token");
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));

        var form = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials"
        };

        requestMessage.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(form);

        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);

        string content = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        PayPalAccessToken accessToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PayPalAccessToken>(content);
        return accessToken;
    }
```

Setting:

```
"PayPal": {
    "clientId": "xxx",
    "secret": "xxx",
    "urlAPI": "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com",
    "returnUrl": "https://localhost:44370/cart/success",
    "cancelUrl": "https://localhost:44370/cart/cancel"
}
```

And here is Code I followed https://gist.github.com/jakejscott/1b829ca1c9449e4788710867f346e90f

Full my code https://paste.mod.gg/ayoqinotis.csharp

What is the problem that I am facing?

Comment: Are you sure you are using correct sandbox credentials? Create a new sandbox Rest APP and post the clientid/secret you are using for it, as well as the full error you are receiving which will include a PayPal-Debug-Id

Comment: @PrestonPHX I tried creating a new sandbox app and assigning client id and secret to it but still the same.

Comment: In that case update your question with the information I mentioned so others can verify. If you can log your API request's text exactly as it is transmitted, that will also be useful.